# Schedule a one-time execution of a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How do I schedule a one-time execution of a stored procedure for a specific time? Basically, my requirement is to handle incoming requests of (Process, TimeToRunIt).

I want to avoid using a 10-second SQL Server Agent Job to keep checking whether it is time to execute. And from my understand Service Broker is meant for queuing executions to run as soon as possible.

A workaround I can imagine is to use a highly-paralleled Service Broker queue (high maximum thread limit) for the scheduled execution request and to use 
`WAITFOR`, but there has to be a better (non-hackish) way, right?

Thanks.

Comment: So it's not really one time, just on-demand?

Comment: One-time, specific time, on demand, dynamically... When are you wanting this thing to be kicked off?

Comment: Dynamically created SQL Agent job with schedule type set to "One time"? Plus garbage collector job that runs, say, once a day.

Comment: When a request comes in to execute a process at a specified time.

Comment: Where is the demand to run it coming from?  A web app?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a one time schedule for an SSIS job.

When adding the SSIS package, go to Schedules>New>Schedule type>One Time. Then choose the Date & Time values under "One-time occurrence".

That's it!

It sounds like you are trying to schedule jobs "on demand" which really is more than once. Just not on a schedule like a SQL Agent Job. In that case, the SSISDB is most likely what you want to use. You can trigger jobs using system stored procedures included in the SSISDB. For example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-start-execution-ssisdb-database

```
Declare @execution_id bigint  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Child1.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'TestDeply4', @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null  
Select @execution_id 

DECLARE @var0 sql_variant = N'Child1.dtsx'  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'Parameter1', @parameter_value=@var0  

DECLARE @var1 sql_variant = N'Child2.dtsx'  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'Parameter2', @parameter_value=@var1 

DECLARE @var2 smallint = 1  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var2  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id  
GO
```